# deploying application on tomcat server status is ok but hitting the url throws 404 not found

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I have been put in to the project involving Spring, Hibernate, Drools, RabbitMq . Though I have no idea of how drools work in coherence with Spring,Hibernate etc but I need to learn it in no time because the project is **all ready functioning and is in production** .So for working on it I thought of setting up the system first and then understand and work on the related ticket....

**Problem in setting up the system goes like this...**

- I configured tomcat   then deployed
- drools over it   drools is up and
- running I created a category to store.drl file containing rules.
- Created a package for storing rules
- uploaded POJO class uploaded the application jar file saved and validated configuration
- I finally deployed my application jar file on server and made it run

so far everything went smooth..and server also showed no problem but when i am hitting this " http://hostname:port/succor-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT/ " on my address bar i am getting good old scary **"404 not found"** i went running to catalina.out to check log and to my horror it is not showing any error ... I am puzzled and confused ... why it is not showing any error in catalina.out if it is throwing 404 on my face...

Answer (score 0):

check for server context in (i think server.xml) it may not like that succor-impl-1.0-SNAPSHOT business in the URL. It could be they are setting "succor" or "somefriendly_name" in server-context.

Thats my shot in the dark!